# Workaround to prevent jquery from causing infinite loop when attaching an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab data from a form and do stuff with that data when a user clicks the continue button after filling said form out. The button (and rest of the page) is 3rd party, and the button has 2 event listeners already waiting for a click event. I have this code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const captureFormData = () => {
    const inputs = {
      fName: document.getElementById("txtFName").value,
      lName: document.getElementById("txtLName").value,
      ssn1: document.getElementById("txtSSN1").value,
      ssn2: document.getElementById("txtSSN2").value,
      ssn3: document.getElementById("txtSSN3").value,
      phone: document.getElementById("txtHomePhone").value
    };

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(inputs);

    console.log("inputs: ", jsonData);
  };

  const continueButtonHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior
    captureFormData();
    $(this).off("click");
  };

  // Attach the event listener to a parent element
  $(document).on("click", ".div-continue > .div-continue-button", continueButtonHandler);
});
```

This doesn't loop because I'm turning off the click event, but I'm worried doing so will cause the pre-existing event listeners to never fire. I have tried several variations of recommended answers, such as this:

```
  const continueButtonHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior

        captureFormData();

        // Continue with pre-existing event listeners on the button
        $(this).off("click"); // Temporarily remove event listener to prevent infinite loop
        $(this).click(); // Trigger click event to continue with pre-existing event listeners
      };
```

but obviously, triggering the click event again is just going to cause an infinite loop. How can I work around this so I attach my button handler as an event listener, allow the pre-existing event listeners to run, but not cause any looping?

Comment: Just attach the listener to the button directly instead of a parent element and understand that you don't need to invoke `click()` to get a listener to run, you can just call the listener by name.

Comment: @ScottMarcus this button doesn't have an ID though, is that still possible?

Comment: Of course. ID's create brittle code and should be avoided when possible. You can still reference any element via its class or by its position within the DOM.

Comment: Ahh. Am I not doing that already? I may just have a bad leftover comment there. I'm referencing the button class itself, through its parent element as a few other buttons have that same class name as well. i.e. ".div-continue > .div-continue-button"

Comment: Do you want to access a single element, rather than all the ones with the same class?

Comment: Yes. A very specific button. I'm going to pack this data up and send it to a separate API, so I only want it triggered when that specific button is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253904/discussion-between-kastaplastislife-and-scott-marcus).